# How to add object of methods into Array Object to use along the project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i want to do something like this

```
 class lapla {
     constructor(array){
        this.array = 
     }
     sum = () => this.array.reduce((p , c) => p + c , 0) //this function sum up all of the array items
 }

 Array.prototype.awesome = new lapla( /* i want to add here the array context*/ this)

 console.log([1,2,3].awesome.sum()   // i want to sum up all array items
```

but this approach doesn't work as you know
how i can achieve something like that

Comment: Seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what motivates you to do this? Because it seems like an overly complex approach. Perhaps a simpler one might be better.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience,  but what I want is : making a small library  to help me to do some processes on arrays easily and  the sum function is for exampling here . i want to write something like that at the end [1,2,3].mylibrary.sum() to sum up all array items

Comment: How about extending the array class? `class MyArray extends Array { sum() { /* your code */} }` can do that without having to modify built-in objects. It's considered very bad practice to change native prototypes. Another alternative is make a wrapper and then use it like `yourLib([1, 2, 3]).sum()`. Then you just need to consume arrays. The simplest would be to only define functions that take all the data you need: `sum([1, 2, 3])`. The last two approaches are used by libraries like Lodash where you can use a function or wrap your input and call methods.

Comment: i want to add only one object to array prototype, and i think this will not affect badly to my project , but in turn i will able to write more compact code , just to write [1,2,3].mylibrary.sum()

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

Array.prototype.sum = function() {
return this.reduce((sum , key)=> sum + key )
}

console.log(array.sum())
```

### Multiple Property

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const objectFunctions = {
  sum: {
    value: function() {
      return this.reduce((cS, key) => cS + key)
    }
  },
  multiply: {
    value: function() {
      return this.reduce((cS, key) => cS * key)
    }
  }
}

Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, objectFunctions );

console.log(array.multiply());
console.log(array.sum())
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i want to wrap all my methods inside an object . so i can find them all inside it. and this enable me to write something like array.awesome.sum()